# How can I disable only checkbox columns in pyside6 QTreeWidget?

Tags: pyside6, qtreewidget

```py
import sys,random 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QTreeWidgetItem,QTreeWidget,QHeaderView,QWidget,QLineEdit 
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont 

class TreeWidget(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self): 
        
        super(). __init__() 
        self.setWindowTitle("List Box Samples") 
        self.TreeWidget = QTreeWidget(self) 
        self.TreeWidget.resize(600,700) 
        ch_font = QFont() 
        ch_font.setBold(True) 
        ch_font.setPointSize(12) 
        
        self.TreeWidget.setColumnCount(2) 
        self.TreeWidget.setHeaderLabels(['  Test1  ','  Test2  ']) 
        self.TreeWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True) 
        
        self.TreeWidget.header().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter) 
        self.TreeWidget.header().setFont(ch_font) 
        self.TreeWidget.header().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents) 
        self.TreeWidget.header().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents) 
        
        self.TreeWidget.setFont(ch_font) 
        a = random.randint(1,2) 
        for i in range(5): 
            item = QTreeWidgetItem(self.TreeWidget) 
            item.setText(0,"Test root") 
            item.setText(1,"Test str") 
            for i in range(10): 
                child_item = QTreeWidgetItem(item) 
                child_item.setCheckState(0,Qt.Checked) 
                child_item.setText(0,str(i)) 
                child_item.setText(1,"Test"+str(i)) 
        
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    win = TreeWidget() 
    win.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to disable only the checkstate column.
child_item = QTreeWidgetItem() has no function of setDisabled itself. Also, child_item.setText(0,Qt.Unchecked) does not have a disabled function.
I appreciate it

```
child_item.setDisabled(True)
```

The entire row disabled

Comment: With "I want to disable" do you mean that you want to prevent the user to toggle the check state?

Comment: It's not that you can't check it. I can check it, but I want to prevent it from checking.

Comment: So, that's *exactly* what I wrote before: you want to prevent the *user* to check it.

Comment: First of all, thank you. But that code doesn't show the checkbox. I want to create a state where the user can check if the checkbox is currently checked or not, but can't touch the checkbox. Is there a way?

Comment: sorry but your comment doesn't make a lot of sense: "I want to create a state where the user can check if the checkbox is currently checked or not, but can't touch the checkbox." > Do you mean "I want to create a state where the user can ***see*** if the checkbox is currently checked or not"?

Comment: I do. I want the task to either make its own checkbox disabled or disabled the 0th column itself so that the checkbox can see if the check is checked in or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt provides *higher level* item view classes to their basic model/view pairs. Those classes are intended for basic usage and interaction (both for the user and on the programming side).

QTreeWidget items automatically sets a `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable` flag on a *whole* row whenever `setCheckState` is explicitly called on an item.

Unfortunately, this has a drawback: it automatically makes a checked item interactive for the check box, so the user can toggle it.

Assuming that you only want to show a checked item for a single column, the solution is quite simple: *unset* the `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable` flag for the item; this won't prevent the view to show the check box, but it will prevent the user to change its value:

```py
# ...
for i in range(10): 
    child_item = QTreeWidgetItem(item) 
    child_item.setCheckState(0,Qt.Checked) 
    child_item.setFlags(child_item.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
    # ...
```

I strongly suggest you to carefully read (and patiently study and experiment with) the whole documentation about the Qt [model/view programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html) in order to better understand how the whole system works.